# WCF throws Exception When the passed list size is large

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I use WCF in my application. from Application I Pass a list to process at backend through WCF. If the no Of rows in the list is large then The service throws the exception "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request."

below is my UI web config

```
<system.serviceModel>

<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="10:20:00"
      openTimeout="10:20:00" receiveTimeout="10:20:00" sendTimeout="10:20:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">

        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />

      </security>

    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" closeTimeout="10:20:00"
      openTimeout="10:20:00" receiveTimeout="10:20:00" sendTimeout="10:20:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

      <security mode="None">

        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />

      </security>

    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" closeTimeout="10:20:00"
      openTimeout="10:20:00" receiveTimeout="10:20:00" sendTimeout="10:20:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

      <security mode="None">

        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />

      </security>

    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService" closeTimeout="10:20:00"
      openTimeout="10:20:00" receiveTimeout="10:20:00" sendTimeout="10:20:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

      <security mode="None">

        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />

      </security>

    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>

  <endpoint address="http://localhost:6789/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:6789/ErrorService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" contract="ErrorServiceReference.IErrorService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:6789/SecurityUserService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService"
    contract="SecurityUserServiceReference.ISecurityUserService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:6789/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" contract="ServiceReference.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" />

</client>

</system.serviceModel>
```

also added the below tag To WCF Web config as well as UI Web config

```
<system.web>

      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000" />

  </system.web>
```

MY service Config is As below

```
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000" />
```

ServiceModel :

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>      
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

I modified the  **service Web config**  . still i am getting the Same issue. Please help me on this

```
<services>

  <service name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
              contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"/>        
  </service>
  <service name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService"
              contract="ErrorServiceReference.IErrorService"/>

  </service>
  <service name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService"
              contract="SecurityUserServiceReference.ISecurityUserService"/>

  </service>

</services>

and bindings

<bindings>

 <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="10:20:00"
    openTimeout="10:20:00" receiveTimeout="10:20:00" sendTimeout="10:20:00"
    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
        realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
  </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IErrorService" closeTimeout="10:20:00"
      openTimeout="10:20:00" receiveTimeout="10:20:00" sendTimeout="10:20:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityUserService" closeTimeout="10:20:00"
      openTimeout="10:20:00" receiveTimeout="10:20:00" sendTimeout="10:20:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

</bindings>
```

Comment: Please post your **service** config - the error is happening when you pass the object to your service - the client bindings regarding size have no effect on the sizes the binding for the service use.

Comment: I have updated my service config above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have any endpoints or bindings defined in your service config, which means you're getting default endpoints and bindings.  Since your service is using the default binding and its default values, it can't receive the large message.

You can override the default binding settings by omitting the `name` attribute in the binding element.  However, in your case you have different settings in your three defined bindings (in the security portion, at least).  So you'll need to both define the bindings and assign them to endpoints.

Try something like this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" .....>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I've omitted most of the binding declaration - you can simply copy them from your client config.

Then in the service you assign a specific binding configuration with the `bindingConfig` attribute on the endpoint element, like this:

```
<services>
  <service .... >
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:6789/Service1.svc"  
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
              contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" 
              name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Again, I've omitted most of the configuration code for simplicity.

The key point here is that the service needs to have a binding that is configured to accept larger messages than the defaults.  Increasing the `maxRequestLength` for the runtime doesn't affect the WCF services directly (unless you have request larger than the HTTP runtime value, of course).

You can read more about default endpoints and bindings here - [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)